# Implementing a transformer-based span retrieval model for a document-grounded dialogue system

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am working on a project that aims to develop a document-grounded dialogue system with a transformer-based span retrieval model. The system will be trained on a dataset of multiturn conversations where users ask questions that require information from multiple documents.

I am currently struggling with the implementation of the transformer-based span retrieval model. Specifically, I am having difficulty with encoding the query and relevant documents and computing the attention scores between them.

However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to compute the attention scores between the query and the document. Can anyone provide guidance on how to properly implement a transformer-based span retrieval model for a document-grounded dialogue system using the Hugging Face Transformers library?

I am using the Hugging Face Transformers library to implement the model. Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import transformers

query = "What is the capital city of Turkey?"
document = "Ankara is the capital city of Turkey."

tokenizer = transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = transformers.AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

query_encoded = tokenizer.encode(query, return_tensors="pt")
document_encoded = tokenizer.encode(document, return_tensors="pt")

query_outputs = model(query_encoded)
document_outputs = model(document_encoded)

attention_scores = torch.matmul(query_outputs, document_outputs.transpose(0, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You interpreted your problem too complicated, I think what you need is simple semantic search problem. For the semantic search task I recommend using the [sentences-transformers](https://www.sbert.net/) library.

Here is a simple code using transformers library:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
import torch


# Sentences we want get sentence embeddings
sentences = ["What is the capital city of Turkey?", "Ankara is the capital city of Turkey.", "Vietnam has a lot of delicious food!"]

# Load model from HuggingFace Hub, note that: bert-base-cased hasn't been trained for the semantic search task
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
# Tokenize sentences
encoded_input = tokenizer(sentences, padding=True, truncation=True, return_tensors='pt')

# Compute token embeddings
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    model_output = model(**encoded_input, return_dict=True)

# Get first token embedding of last layer as cls token embedding
sentence_embeddings = model_output["last_hidden_state"][:, 0]

print(f"Similarity S1 vs S2:\n {sentence_embeddings[0]@sentence_embeddings[1]}")
print(f"Similarity S1 vs S3:\n {sentence_embeddings[0]@sentence_embeddings[2]}")
```

output:

```
Similarity S1 vs S2:
 279.5570068359375
Similarity S1 vs S3:
 268.71270751953125
```

using sentences-transformers is much more easier:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
import torch

embedder = SentenceTransformer('all-MiniLM-L6-v2')

# Corpus with example sentences
corpus = ["Ankara is the capital city of Turkey.",
          "Vietnam has a lot of delicious food!"]
corpus_embeddings = embedder.encode(corpus, convert_to_tensor=True)

# Query sentences:
queries = ['What is the capital city of Turkey?', "What's interesting about Vietnam?"]


# Find the closest 5 sentences of the corpus for each query sentence based on cosine similarity
top_k = min(5, len(corpus))
for query in queries:
    query_embedding = embedder.encode(query, convert_to_tensor=True)

    # We use cosine-similarity and torch.topk to find the highest 5 scores
    cos_scores = util.cos_sim(query_embedding, corpus_embeddings)[0]
    top_results = torch.topk(cos_scores, k=top_k)

    print("\n\n======================\n\n")
    print("Query:", query)
    print("\nTop similar sentences in corpus:")

    for score, idx in zip(top_results[0], top_results[1]):
        print(corpus[idx], "(Score: {:.4f})".format(score))
```

output:

```
======================


Query: What is the capital city of Turkey?

Top similar sentences in corpus:
Ankara is the capital city of Turkey. (Score: 0.8318)
Vietnam has a lot of delicious food! (Score: 0.2655)


======================


Query: What's interesting about Vietnam?

Top similar sentences in corpus:
Vietnam has a lot of delicious food! (Score: 0.6315)
Ankara is the capital city of Turkey. (Score: 0.0667)
```

Comment: Thank you!
This approach is a straightforward yet effective method. However, unlike a document-grounded dialogue system, this code only retrieves relevant sentences from the document corpus and does not generate a response.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but if you want to generate an answer you need to add a model to generate a complete answer, the task of the retrieval model is just to find the documents that relevant to the question.